# Cannot Find Symbol for simple primitive type

Tags: java, symbols, netbeans-8, smartfoxserver

I don't know if this is real life, but I'm getting a Cannot find symbol after I just declared a simple string and when I try to assign the value it gets the cannot find symbol. This happens even if it is static or another primitive type.I'm assuming it's something configuration issues.

[image: Cannot find symbol]

Comment: Try adding the access modifier `private` before `String name`. If you do this, you might want to consider initializing `name` in your `Characters` constructor. Or you can declare `name` in a `main` method.

Comment: I can initialize on the constructor but now I cannot use a getter and setter to modify that variable, if I try to use those methods I get a "invalid method declaration, return type required".

Comment: You can create your own like this: Getter: `public String getName() {return name;}` Setter: `public void setName(String newName) {name = newName;}`

Comment: You need an initializer block, a constructor, or a method to contain that assignment. Or, you could say `String name = " ";` Note that you are creating an instance field `name` with package-private access permissions. **And**, a `String` is a reference type - not a *primitive*.

Comment: Also String is not a primitive type, it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

In java class you can declare or define (initialize at the same time) variables but not set any values or initialize them later. The second line can only be done in a method body or a constructor.

Example 1:

```
public class Test
{
   String name;

   void doStuff(){
      name = "  ";
   }
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class Test
{
   String name = "set some value";
}
```

You can read more about it [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).